# What is the most efficient way to render a dynamic menu

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

What is the most efficient way to make a dynamic menu, in my database I have different user roles and each role has different permissions to access pages, what would be the best way to create a menu that is generated every time you access. What would be the best way to avoid slow loading of the page?

I'm using the technologies: Primefaces, JSF, java..

Comment: What is the current loading time ? Where is it taking time, on the server or browser ? how did you structure your permissions table ? And what is the query that you execute to get the permissions from db ?

Comment: did you think in user in role ( that's mean create roles in your application )

Answer (score 0):

Your question directly not connected with JSF. You should develop your application logic yourself, JSF/Primefaces just can help you render menu in fron tend.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was referring to rendering, I already have the database logic and I actually made a rendering form, but every time I loaded a page I called all the permissions, which made it a bit slow on the server

Comment: ok I understand, create SessionScoped bean , after first login put permission on its, create Permission Context for you, and after every time instead of db get permission from that bean. If it is important you can have background job which will get fresh data from database and update session bean for example each 10 minutes

Comment: For example here user credentials after login set in the session bean and used in the frontend logic https://github.com/armdev/jsf-web-app/blob/master/web-platform/src/main/java/com/project/web/auth/UserLogin.java

Comment: Thank you very much,I will try to do it